# How to create a Time object from time_select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is the following params hash: `{"start_time(5i)":"00","start_time(4i)":"06","start_time(3i)":"17","start_time(2i)":"1","start_time(1i)":"2014"}`

As you can see these are parts of time and I need to create a new Time object from it. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
datetime = DateTime.strptime("#{params['start_time']['(1i)']}-#{params['start_time']['(2i)']}-#{params['start_time']['(3i)']}T#{params['start_time']['(4i)']}:#{params['start_time']['(5i)']}", '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M')
```

[strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime)